# Reading password locked text files with python

Tags: python, file-locking

I'm currently making some foodie program for fun. I want to put some information in .txt file and read it later with my python code. But my problem is that I don't want users to be able to approach text file so they won't be able to delete text inside and stuff. So I was checking around and found program "Lock My Folders". It will require password to enter .txt, but the problem is that I'm not that experienced, just finished Free code camp course and trying to improve and I have never encountered such a problem and I don't know how to write code which will enter password automatically when script try to open it. Any1 got some better idea for locking or preventing user to play around with .txt file?. Thanks!

Comment: How would you then hide your password from the users?

Comment: I would suggest practice using a proper data store for applications such as a database. [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/index.html) is a good starting point to integrate a database with Python

Comment: @goalie1998 It's gonna be hidden since I'm making GUI with tkinter and gonna wrap it in .exe

Comment: @im_baby Hey, I did used and connect my sqlite database for list of ingredients and recipes, but I was thinking about importing whole recipe info into .txt and import it from there. Is there any better way to write full recipe in sqlite and import it from there?

Comment: @Pascal Hey, I was thinking about encrypting .txt data, but if user enter and change some text inside it will break the app. With password locking file they can only delete txt and app won't even start. That's why I thought to secure it with password. What do you think?

Comment: Is the text file going to be used/changed multiple times, or is only used for creation of the app?

Comment: @goalie1998 I'm going to write full recipe description inside and whenever user choose one of the recipes python will search for recipe in .txt and return it as string. That is my plan at least :D

Comment: Can you not include it within the wrapped exe file? Or even just save the entire txt file as a string variable to begin with? Or use pickle? But I do agree with @im_baby, a database for this would probably be best.

Comment: @goalie1998 I think its better for me to go with sqlite then because I understand it more than pickle and encrypting files. Can you suggest me any way how to insert whole recipe by stages into database and pull it out with python? I already made database with ingredients and recipes and connected them in junction table. So what I'm thinking now is to make another table named recipe description and connect it with recipe name so it will be easier to pull it out once recipe is chosen in app? What do you think?

Comment: I don't really know much about database management, but you should be able to do that